# Decode (encrypted/encoded) PDF417 Barcode information for Iraqi passport

Tags: encryption, encoding, barcode, decoding, pdf417

I need to read PDF417 barcode for Iraqi passport and extract the information from it.
I scanned the barcode successfully and it contains two parts, first part is the MRZ and the second part is an encoded/encrypted text. so is there a way to know the method used to encode this text and how to decode it?

this is the encoded/encrypted part:

**|Rk1SACAyMAAAAADcAAABYAF9AMUAxQEAAQA/IEBLAFt0AEBNAH98AEBZAJYAAEBjAMP8AEBmATj0AEB+AEmMAEClADEoAECLAC0oAECJAHEMAECqALQIAECLALgAAECoANsEAEB7AMiAAEB+AUF4AEDIAF0gAEDGAFCkAECzAFIgAECvAKeMAEDlAJQcAEDjAGQgAEDfAPUIAEDCAOOMAEC7AP8AAEDVAVEAAEDBAVCAAEDYASKAAIDFAT0AAED2AJqcAED8AJQcAEDsAQUEAEEVAPmUAEDqAVGEAA==|**

Comment: If you already have the MRZ, isn't that enough? What extra data do you need? Or are you just curious what is stored there? It might just be a digital signature on the data you have.

Comment: Linux's file says it's a base64-encoded ISO/IEC 19794-2 Format Minutiae Record (FMR), which sounds like it's fingerprint or other biometric data.

Comment: I Just need extra information like the Mother name and date of issue which don't exist in the MRZ and I thought that I may find them in the Barcode. thanks for the information.

Comment: It it has got a chip inside of it then it may contains, uh, I think it is Data Group 11 (DG11), which contains additional information. Yep, my memory serves me right, "DG11  Additional Personal Details"... Data element 1 & 2 contain "full name" 99 chars max and "other names" 99 chars max...

Answer (score -1):

Go to https://www.base64decode.org/, copy and paste your text and remove the bar `|` symbol from the beginning and ending. Then select `ISO-8859-6` as the character set and click the DECODE button. You'd have to exclude certain characters from the result to piece together the actual contents.